# LAN client attempting to connect to many unkown IPs on Boot

Tags: networking, malware

I have a Zywall 110 Firewall.  While perusing the logs I was seeing random bursts of attempted connections to unknown external IP addresses from a single LAN client computer. I noticed because I would see a number of successive

```
Session Limit - Maximum session per host (1000) was exceeded. [count=x] localIP RemoteIP
```

This will happen for about a minute and cause about 25 notices per incident.  One notice for each external IP that is trying to be connected to.

I spoke with the terminal operator and the timing appears to be when the user reboots the terminal and it first comes back online. I suspected malware or a virus, but scans don't turn up anything suspicious.

Any ideas what might be causing this, or what additional information I need to troubleshoot?

Comment: Virus scans only detect *known* viruses. Custom malware designed for a targeted attack will go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a malconfigured network adapter, you should do the following: Assuming you have a live boot USB or CD, try to live boot the client and see if you can replicate the behavior. If not, use wireshark to monitor the connections.

What protocols is the client trying to use?